# stereo-aware composite manager for Nvidia 3d vision

Tags: 3d, nvidia, composite

Recently Nvidia released [beta (337.12) drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/75340/en-us) for NVIDIA graphics card. 3D Stereo with the composite extension on Quadro cards has been released in this driver. I am using compiz in ubuntu 12.04 which is not stereo-aware. What are the available composite managers that are stereo-aware?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I got from emailing Andy Ritger of Nvidia. It seems Owen Taylor of Red Hat is updating gnome/mutter to be stereo-aware.

```
https://git.gnome.org/browse/clutter/log/?h=wip/quadbuffer-stereo
https://git.gnome.org/browse/mutter/log/?h=wip/quadbuffer-stereo
```

"    https://git.gnome.org/browse/cogl/log/?h=wip/quadbuffer-stereo"
"    https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/log/?h=wip/quadbuffer-stereo"

BR